# mysql extra count field for each row

Tags: mysql, count, row, field, duplicate-data

I have a query here, anyone can help me to count the total duplicated fields?

```
SELECT *
FROM item
    INNER JOIN itemgroup on item.itemgroupid = itemgroup.itemgroupid    
    INNER JOIN status on status.statusid = item.status
    INNER JOIN owner on owner.ownerid = item.owner
    INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT code  //, (SELECT count(*) FROM item WHERE ....) as 'total_duplicateds'
      FROM item
      GROUP BY code
      HAVING count(code) > 1
    ) dup ON item.code = dup.code
```

Total items: 500
Total items with duplicated codes: 149

Now I get a total of 149 fields returned, how can I add this as a new field to each row?
After the slash is how I learnt to do it but this is a little higher level for me..

Can someone help me out?

**To be even more specific**
What I'd like to get returned is like:

```
itemid | code| itemname | itemgroup | owner | total_duplicateds
   1     1000      X          1         1            3
   2     1000      X          2         2            3
   3     1001      A          1         1            3
   4     1000      B          3         1            3
   5     1002      U          2         1            3
```

Comment: can you give sample records? much better if you posted it on [SQLFiddle.com](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 0):

Add `COUNT` aggregation and `GROUP BY` all columns that are interesting you.